# XSLT : Delete HTML node if attribute and text value match condition

Tags: xslt

Am new to XSLT and i have a task to delete all `<a> tags` that have attribute `class="LinkSQL"` and text value `Source`

Sample HTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="R">
                        <a class="LinkSQL" href="#">Source</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="R">
                        <a class="LinkSQL" href="#">Media</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="R">
                        <a class="LinkSQL" href="#">News</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="R">
                        <a class="LinkSQL" href="#">Source</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[@class='LinkSQL']|LinkSQL" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expectation is to delete these complete block `<a class="LinkSQL" href="#">Source</a>`. My xslt deletes all `<a>` tags. Appreciate any feedback

Expected Output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="R">
                        <a class="LinkSQL" href="#">Media</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="R">
                        <a class="LinkSQL" href="#">News</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> delete all `<a>` tags that have attribute `class="LinkSQL"` and text value `Source`

That would be:

```
<xsl:template match="a[@class='LinkSQL'][.='Source']" />
```

or:

```
<xsl:template match="a[@class='LinkSQL' and .='Source']" />
```

---

Note that your stylesheet says `version="1.0"` but `xpath-default-namespace` requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate it